# JQuery: changes applied to DOM but not reflected in the browser

Tags: jquery, dom

On my page, I run:

```
someElementWrappedByJQuery.hide();
alert (someElementWrappedByJQuery.css('display'));
```

**The result:**
I see the element shown on the page, like hide() didn't work. 
However, the alerted value is "none"

More info:

- it's not only a hide() problem. Many different commands that are run, don't have a real effect, but seem to be somehow applied to the DOM when I query about them programatically.
- When I move someElementWrappedByJQuery to other place on the page (above some point, which I'm not sure exactly what it is), the problem disappears.
- Problem seen in chrome and IE

Any ideas what can be going on here?

edit: solved, see my answer to myself below. and I see that someone has suggested this

Thanks

Gidi

Comment: "Any ideas what can be going on here?" yep, a few. But if you could post a live demo reproducing your problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) we could probably tell you **exactly** what's going on. Which would be infinitely more useful to you =)

Comment: do you have multiple divs with same ids??

Comment: @show us your html and jquery code , we can easily fix

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...

Solved.

The element someElementWrappedByJQuery has already been on the page, added as a hidden elemnt by someone else

Now, I added another one. So all the commands were applied to the other one, and not to the one I added.

When I moved mine, above the point where the hiddent element was placed, obviously the problem disappeared.

Comment: moving the element is not a solution, it's a workaround. The solution is to ensure that you do not have two or more elements with the same ID (as @gov said above). This is not legal, so just moving your element and keeping duplicate IDs may well break your webpage in the future.